# Image added through JLabel as jpg format is not clear in java swing gui

Tags: java, imageicon

```java
package project;

import javax.swing.*;

class login {
    
    JFrame loginf;
    JLabel loginimg;
    
    public void start() {
        loginf = new JFrame();
        loginf.setSize(1280,720);
        loginf.setLayout(null);
        loginf.setUndecorated(true);
        loginf.setLocation(120,60);

        loginimg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("E:\\well\\Login with image1.jpg"));
        loginimg.setBounds(0,0,1280,720);

        loginf.add(loginimg);
        loginf.setVisible(true);    
    }
}

public class LoginPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        login lp = new login();
        lp.start(); 
    }
}
```

[Image is not clear i edited the image in photoshop and the same image has quite good when i open it from pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgIu2.png)

Comment: If your image has to expand to fill the space it will pixelate.  Make sure your image is bigger than the space to be filled.

Comment: Why would you want to put up an image that *looks like* a login form btw?

Comment: Your platform is scaling the application so the image is getting pixelated. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742162/how-to-fix-the-blurry-image-when-i-run-my-java-swing-project/65742492#65742492 for a couple of options. Also, don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.