# Java ImageIcon Low Definition Display

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

In java, why is it that when I import an image and convert it to ImageIcon and display it using JLabel or JButton, it results to a low definition image where I can see the pixels at the edges of my images

To solve the low definition display of ImageIcon

Comment: Are you running on Windows with a monitor resolution > 100%?

Comment: This could be issues with your image itself

Comment: [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285911/low-quality-image-icon).