# Misunderstanding or usage of BaseMultiResolutionImage: upscaled images are "scratchy"

Tags: java, image, label, icons

I have a small app that displays a random image. I've noticed that the image became blurry on Windows desktops with up-scaled text size from this settings:

[image]

So, I read about using BaseMultiResolutionImage and tried implementing that: my image is no longer blurry, but becomes "scratchy" when I get over 150% scale... For example, on a Windows scaling of 175%:

[image]

Left: Java app is scratchy
Right: Actual Image file is smooth.

Here's a full code example:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BaseMultiResolutionImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test app = new Test();
      app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      app.setVisible(true);
   }

   public Test(){
      super("Test App");

      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

      JLabel lblImage = new JLabel();
      lblImage.setIcon(this.getNoteIcon());
      lblImage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
      panel.add(lblImage, gbc);

      getContentPane().add(panel);
        pack();
   }

    ImageIcon getNoteIcon(){
        try {
            List<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<Image>();

            /* all images are width = 108 height = 83 */
            imgList.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/scale_100.png"))); // 100% - 108x83
            imgList.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/scale_125.png"))); // 125% - 135x104
            imgList.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/scale_150.png"))); // 150% - 162x124
            imgList.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/scale_175.png"))); // 175% - 189x145
            imgList.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/scale_200.png"))); // 200% - 216x166

            BaseMultiResolutionImage multiResolutionImage = new BaseMultiResolutionImage(imgList.toArray(new Image[0]));
            return new ImageIcon(multiResolutionImage);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
  }
}
```

What I did is that I created one image file per scales, i.e.:

image @ 100% = 108x83 
... 
image @ 175% = 189x145 (108x83 * 175%)

and then added one after the other into the ArrayList of images. From these, created the BaseMultiResolutionImage...

Am I doing anything wrong here? If so, what please? I don't understand how to fix this.

I'm also including the test image files:

[image: scale 100]
[image: scale 125]
[image: scale 150]
[image: scale 175]
[image: scale 200]

Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried using a base size that is a multiple of 4 in both dimensions, like 108x84? This will avoid rounding errors (ie. 83*1.75 isn't exactly 145, but 145.25).

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll give it a try and update here asap. Cheers

Comment: @HaraldK Okay. I think I managed to get it: I ended up adding 2 pixels to my base highres image, and setting my 100% one to 110x84. From that, calculated that base number * 125%, 150%, 175% .... If one of them gave me a fraction (i.e. 110x84 * 125% = 137.5/105), I ended rounding UP + adding a pixel: 139x106. 

This happened to 125% and 175% obviously... What a pain in the as!@?% to fix!!! I got them all to 300%. If someone zooms their damn screen beyond that, they need to stop using computers! lol

Anyhow, thanks for putting me in the right direction :)