# How to add good quality image to JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

After inserting a good quality image into the JLabel, the final image quality is less detailed (as if it had a lower resolution).[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9446d.jpg) [JFrame screen after inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41WIQ.jpg). The difference may not be so visible in the images presented, but in reality it is very noticeable that the quality in JFrame is lower.

My setup: 1. Java 17 version, 2. Windows 11 Pro 23H2 (125% scaling factor), 3. Display has 141 ppi, 4. Image has 911x406 dimension and 96 dpi.

My code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setSize(1300, 800);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/resources/scheme.jpg"));
JLabel schemeLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
schemeLabel.setBounds(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
frame.add(schemeLabel);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: You most likely have screen scaling active. So you should include 1. Java version, 2. Operating system & version, 3. Screen DPI settings. Besides that: • Do not access the source folder. When you build an application, there won’t be a source folder. Learn how to use resources. • Do not use a `null` layout. • If you use manual sizing and placement, be consistent. Don’t mix hardcode sizes like `frame.setSize(1300, 800);` with dynamic/external values like `schemeLabel.setBounds(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());`

Comment: 1. Java 17 version, 2. Windows 11 Pro 23H2, 3. Screen has 141 ppi.  4. Image has 911x406 dimension and 96 dpi.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the information. It’s also important which scaling factor has been set for the display.

Comment: 125% scaling factor set for the display.

Comment: *125% scaling factor set for the display* - which would be the problem.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65742492/131872

Comment: Setting System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0") helped me solve my problem.